# what is wrong in this code in copy constructer?

Tags: java

Number class

```
class Number 
{
Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
int[] arr;
int n;
String name;
Number()
{

    System.out.print("Enter List Size :");
    this.n = input.nextInt();
    this.arr = new int[n];
    for(int i =0;i<n;i++)
    {
        System.out.print("Enter a Number :");
        this.arr[i] = input.nextInt();
    }
}

Number(Number O)
{
    this.n = O.n;
    this.arr = O.arr;

}
void Read_Number()
{
    for(int i =0;i<n;i++)
    {
        System.out.print("Enter a Number :");
        arr[i] = input.nextInt();
    }
}}
```

after creating copy constructer if I make changes in object O2 then that similar changes also occured in object O1.

```
public class MyList {


public static void main(String[] args) 
{       Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

        Number O1 = new Number();
        Number O2 = new Number(O1);
           }
}
```

why and what is solution?

Comment: You can't just do this: `this.arr = O.arr;`. You'll have to copy each element of the array.

Answer (score 3):

Your copy constructor doesn't create a copy of the array member of the original class.

You need to make a copy :

```
Number(Number O)
{
    this.n = O.n;
    this.arr = Arrays.copyOf(O.arr,O.arr.length);
}
```

When you only copy a reference to the original array, both `Number` instances refer to the same array, and changes in the array of one of the instances are reflected in the other instance.

Comment: Length is O.arr.length or? EDIT: too late^^

Answer (score 2):

An int[] is a reference data type. If you copy it to a new object, you are copying the reference, not the object it points to. This will fix your issue:

```
Number(Number O)
{
    this.n = O.n;
    this.arr = Arrays.copyOf(O.arr, O.arr.length);

}
```